# Nested Parameterization in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, quality-assurance

I wanted to parameterize a set of values within another parameterized value. 
(Parameterizing values into a title which is also to be parameterized). Can someone please help me how to go about?

Comment: Welcome. Have a look at [asking questions](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/asking). You might get downvotes for [no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), among other reasons. It is hard to provide an answer with so little information. What (underlying) problem are you trying to solve? What did you try? What failed?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you're looking for [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) which can be used for evaluation of nested variables

For example, if you have

- `VAR_1` = `foo`
- `VAR_2`= `1`

and would like to get `${VAR1_${VAR_2}`= `foo`

The relevant syntax would be `${__V(VAR_${VAR_2},)}`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)